# Return JSON with Column names in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have trying to get JSON values whenever result is empty in SQL Server 2016.

**Example:**

```
select Col1,Col2,Col3 from test where Col1 = 2
```

[image]

```
select Col1,Col2,Col3 from test where Col1 = 2 for json auto,include_null_values
```

Then I am getting no JSON value. Giving only empty value.
[image]

**Expected Result:**

```
[{"Col1":"","Col2":"","Col3":""}]
```

Can you please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You won't get anything if there are no matcing rows, JSON or not. There are other ways and queries to retrieve a table's columns. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I want trying to get JSON with column names, if whenever no matching rows there then i am expecting JSON with column headers. Is this possible ?

Comment: I already explained that if there are no data you won't get any results. A row with empty field values is still a row. Empty fields aren't *NULL* fields either, they are empty. An empty `nvarchar(10)`  field isn't a NULL field. If there are no rows, you get no results. That's the expected and logical outcome.. What are you trying to do in the first place? Why not select the column names eg from `sys.columns` or execute `sp_columns` ?

Answer (score 0):

In case there are no matching rows, your select query will not return any rows either. In this case, you can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (or [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) and return some default string, like the one you expect.

```
select isnull(
    (select Col1,Col2,Col3 from test where Col1 = 2 for json auto,include_null_values) -- Your query as nested select
    , '[{"Col1":"","Col2":"","Col3":""}]' -- This string will be returned if there are no matching rows
)
```

Unfortunately, it isn't easy to get the default string from your query, so you have to duplicate the column names from your `select` query here, but it should not be a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option where you don't have to express the individual columns using:

```
sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set()
```

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f0955113bc0c668be642954fc6573da2)**

```
Create Table #YourTable (Col1 int,Col2 int,Col3 int)
Insert Into #YourTable values 
 (1,25,75)
,(3,50,100)

Select coalesce(
                (Select Col1,Col2,Col3 From  #YourTable Where Col1 = 2 For json auto,include_null_values )
                ,
                (Select '[{'+Stuff((Select  Concat(',"',Name,'":""') From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select * from #YourTable',null,null) For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')+'}]' )
              )
```

**Returns**

```
[{"Col1":"","Col2":"","Col3":""}]
```